# Efficiently enumerating all simple paths of DiGraph in networkx

Tags: python, optimization, graph-theory, shortest-path, networkx

I am attempting to do some graph analysis on the Dewey Decimal Classification, so that I can make a distance between two books. The DDC has several relations: "hierarchy", "see-also", "class-elsewhere", here I represent them with different colours. Since these relations are not symmetric you will notice we have a Directed Graph. Below is a picture of the graph of all vertices maximum 4 edges away from 394.1.

[image: Sample Graph]

The distance metric between classifications A and B, should be the shortest path between A and B. However the colours have no inherent weighted value or preference. But the user will give provide one. So given a dictionary of weights, example:

```
weights_dict_test = {'notational_hiearchy':1,
                'see_reference':0.5, 
                'class_elsewhere':2}
```

I would like to return the weighted shortest path. I thought that would not be a problem if I could preprocess all simple paths between the two nodes, and then find which was the shortest given the weights dict. However since the graph contains >50,000 nodes. Computing `nx.all_simple_paths(G, a, b)` has not returned after 24 hours of computation. Are there any suggestions for parallelizing finding `all_simple_paths`. Or a technique to compute the shortest path given the `weights_dict` that does not involve computing `all_simple_paths`?

Comment: The answer to your question is: yes, there are techniques for this, but the scope is too broad for a good answer here. Try starting here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path

Comment: I suppose also more specifically, it would be implementing one of [directed graphs with nonnegative weights](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path#Directed_graphs_with_nonnegative_weights).

Comment: how are you representing the different relations? is it just if the edge has that attribute? it would probably not take too long to update an edge attribute `weight` based on attributes and the input dict, and then just use the built-in `shortest_path`, which supports weights already. Also, networkx is pure python, and the code for shortest path is available, if you need to modify it for this special case.

Comment: @CorleyBrigman I just tried your suggestion -it works brilliantly. Thank you - problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @CorleyBrigman. The solution is to create a new Graph `W` from `G`, replacing the colours of `G` with weights you desire. Then you can efficiently use the `nx.shortest_path` and `nx.shortest_path_length` with their typically fast runtimes.

```
In [23]:

def update_weights(G, weights_dict):    
    W = nx.DiGraph()

    for m in G.nodes():
        for n in G[m].iterkeys():
            relation = G[m][n]['rel']
            weight = weights_dict[relation]    
            W.add_edge(m, n, rel=weights_dict[relation])            
    return W

In [41]:

weights_dict_test = {'notational_hiearchy':50,
                'see_reference':0.6, 
                'class_elsewhere':1}

In [42]:

W = update_weights(G, weights_dict_test)

In [43]:

print len(W)
print len(G)

43241    
43241

In [45]:

nx.shortest_path_length(W, '394.1', '341.33',weight='rel')

Out[45]:

52.2
```